# Evitar dados duplicados aplicando contador para registo de utilizações

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Num formulário simples que grava os seguintes dados:

> ID, IP, Data/Hora, Nome, Email, Estado/Cidade.

Quando uma pessoa preenche o formulário, este dados são registrados no banco de dados. Mas se o mesmo utilizador for preencher o formulário novamente, vai ser registado um novo registo, criando uma duplicação de informação.

Como posso controlar este cenário de forma a que se a mesma pessoa usar o formulário com os mesmos dados, ao invés de duplicar o registo, incremente apenas um contador de controlo ?

Comment: Qual o tipo de ligação à base de dados que estás a utilizar? [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php), [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) ?

Comment: Já experimentou ir ao W3school, a aprender o básico de SQLi ?
E também podes evitar isso pelo SQL, utilizando o Unique.
`IP => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`
`data => date();`
`hora = time();` // podes sempre criar uma função para escrever em portugues.

Answer (score 1):

A lógica correta é utilizar um destes campos `ID, IP, Data/Hora, Nome, Email e Estado/Cidade` como um **validador**. Você pode utilizar uma espécie de **validação** utilizando o `campo Email`, por exemplo, como referência. O `ip` está fora de questão, uma vez que dentro de uma casa 2 ou mais pessoas, podem utilizar o mesmo ip:

Exemplo:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM table where (email = '$email')";

$duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

if (mysql_num_rows($duberaw) > 0) {

  //FIM DO CADASTRO
  //AVISA QUE JÁ POSSUI UM EMAIL COM ESTES DADOS  
}else{

  //CONTINUA O CADASTRO


}
```

Comment: Removi o trecho que me cita porque eu deletei a resposta.Ok? Não tinha percebido a parte que ele pede pra incrementar um contador

Comment: ok..............

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente sugiro que crie uma chave única com os campos que não podem ser duplicados, dessa forma o próprio MySQL evita a duplicidade.

Por exemplo:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `nome_da_chave` (`nome`, `email`, `cidade`)
```

Com essa chave criada quando tentar inserir um registro duplicado a consulta vai gerar um erro `1022 SQLSTATE: 23000` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key)

Antes de inserir um novo registro você deve consultar a tabela, se não existir o registro pode inserir, caso contrário atualizar.